# Azure pipeline for multiple environments 710202314

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Here is a simple Azure DevOps pipeline in YAML that fits your requirements. This pipeline uses a script task and the Azure Pipelines predefined variables, specifically Build.SourceBranchName to get the branch name that triggered the pipeline.

Please keep in mind that Azure Pipelines does not directly support string contains or regex checks inside YAML, so the operations here are a bit verbose due to use of scripting.

```
variables:
  DevEnvs: "Dev|QA|Test"
  ReleaseEnvs: "Stage|Release|Prod"
  TargetEnvironments: "Dev|Test" # You can set it dynamically during the build

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - Dev*
      - Release*

jobs:
- job: checkBranchAndEnvironments
  displayName: 'Check Branch and Environments'
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Check branch and target environments'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $branch = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
        $targetEnvs = "$(TargetEnvironments)".Split("|")

        if ($branch.StartsWith("Dev")) {
          $devEnvs = "$(DevEnvs)".Split("|")
          foreach ($env in $targetEnvs) {
            if ($env -notin $devEnvs) {
              Write-Error "Environment $env is not valid for Dev branches"
              exit 1
            }
          }
        }
        elseif ($branch.StartsWith("Release")) {
          $releaseEnvs = "$(ReleaseEnvs)".Split("|")
          foreach ($env in $targetEnvs) {
            if ($env -notin $releaseEnvs) {
              Write-Error "Environment $env is not valid for Release branches"
              exit 1
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          Write-Error "Branch $branch is not valid"
          exit 1
        }

  - script: echo $(Build.SourceBranchName)
    displayName: 'Echo branch name'
```